# DNS is not applied with systemd-resolved

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, dns, networkmanager, systemd-resolved

I'm using Kubuntu 18.04. When I'm in the office network, everything works fine, but when I connect to any other network (wired of wifi) I don't get proper DNS names - the old ones are still in `systemd-resolve --status` output. When I add the proper DNS address via `systemd-resolve --set-dns=10.0.0.1 --interface=eno1`, the problem is solved temporarily and I can resolve hostnames, but after a while it stops working and I have to run the `--set-dns` again.

How do I solve this?

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say you have hardcoded DNS servers in your configuration.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro - where can I look for them? I already checked `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` - no mention of them

Comment: Check `/etc/resolv.conf` in the "working" and "not-working" cases. Is it the same or different? Also check the [Arch Wiki page on systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Systemd-resolved&redirect=no) and [alternatives to systemd-resolvconf](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&ei=ljFrW-KrFo7isAWOxqqQBQ&q=systemd-resolvconf+ubuntu&oq=systemd-resolvconf+ubuntu&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i30k1.8261.9218.0.9965.8.7.0.0.0.0.310.811.0j2j1j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..6.2.410...0i7i30k1.0.0RX8kIL5Cdc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be brutal and simple. The DHCP client was superseding the DNS entries in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` via `supersede domain-name-servers ...,...;`. I have no idea why it was there, I must've forgot that I've set this a while back.

The command that saved me:

```
sudo find /etc -type f -print0 2>/dev/null | xargs -0 sudo grep "<hardcoded address>"
```

Yep, simple as that.

Comment: why not just `sudo grep -r "<address>" /etc`?